# tan function giving incorrect values in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use the `tan` function in MATLAB, but it's giving me strange results. Is there anything else I should consider?

```
>> tan(45)

ans =

    1.6198

>> tan(0)

ans =

     0

>> tan(1)

ans =

    1.5574

>> tan(20)

ans =

    2.2372
```

Comment: You should consider reading the first sentence of the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tan.html

Comment: @Dan it's the **last** word of that sentence! It's much easier to post a question on SO that read a **whole** sentence...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like you provide the argument to [`tan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tan.html) in [degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28angle%29). However, Matlab expects its input in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

Try:

```
>> tan( pi / 4 )
```

If you insist on using degrees, you'll find [`tand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tand.html) useful:

```
>> tand( 45 )
```

Remember `rad = deg * pi / 180`